# Dynamic, static or kinematic for an object that moved by accelerometer?

Tags: lua, game-physics, coronasdk

I have this screen:

[image]

I want this ball to be moved using accelerometer and collide with the walls.

When I declared it as dynamic it moved but not collide, when I declared it as dynamic it had a strange trembling in its movement and after a while stop collide and went out of the borders.
My code (for physics and movement function) is:

```
function onTilt( event )

ball.x = (ball.x + event.xGravity * 20)
ball.y=(ball.y+ event.yGravity * 20)
end


physics.addBody ( mazepart1, "static" ,physicsData:get("mazepart1"))
physics.addBody ( mazepart1, "static" ,physicsData:get("mazepart2"))
physics.addBody (borders, "static" ,physicsData:get("borders"))
physics.addBody ( ball, "dynamic" ,physicsData:get("ball1"))

Runtime:addEventListener( "accelerometer", onTilt )
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to change the **x** and **y** of the object because it may move unnatural,
try to change the gravity itself, by change the `physics.setGravity(event.yGravity,event.xGravity)` something like that to make the move realistic. But your object must be **dynamic**.

Let the gravity move your ball.